# Dart argument definition test deprecated?

Tags: dart, conditional-statements, optional-parameters

On Dart 1.0.0, I just tried:

```
class MyClass {
    int x;
    bool b;

    MyClass(int x, [bool b = true]) {
        if(?b) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And am getting a compiler error on the `?b` part:

> The argument definition test ('?' operator) has been deprecated

So what's the "new" way of testing for whether or not an argument was supplied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to test if an argument was provided or not. The main-reason for its removal was, that it was very complex to forward calls this way.

The generally preferred way is to use `null` as "not given". This doesn't always work (for example if `null` is a valid value), and won't catch bad arguments. If `null` is used, then the parameter must not have a default-value. Otherwise the parameter is not null but takes the default-value:

```dart
foo([x = true, y]) => print("$x, $y");
foo();  // prints "true, null"
```

So in your case you should probably do:

```dart
class MyClass {
  int x;
  bool b;

  MyClass(int x, [bool b]) {
    if(b == null) {  // treat as if not given.
        // ...
    }
  }
}
```

This makes `new MyClass(5, null)` and `new MyClass(5)` identical. If you really need to catch the first case, you have to work around the type-system:

```dart
class _Sentinel { const _Sentinel(); }
...
  MyClass(int x, [b = const _Sentinel()]) {
    if (b == const _Sentinel()) b = true;
    ...
  }
```

This way you can check if an argument has been provided. In return you lose the type on `b`.

Comment: This is not best because you omitted type annotation. This require additional test on type compatibility. This not helps check troubles when passing parameter with wrong type. Code that call this function always requires test in in runtime because from function signature not clear what type allowed for parameter. I am about sample with `_Sentinel`.

Comment: (And in that example there is no way to distinguish new MyClass(x) from new MyClass(x, const _Sentinel()) within its library.)

Comment: @mezoni: Read the last sentence.

Comment: @Ganymede: true, but if that starts mattering, you have other problems.

Comment: @FlorianLoitsch Loitsch, I expressed my opinion about the shortcomings. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The argument definition test operator was deprecated because it was redundant with checking for `null`; an optional parameter that was omitted would get the value `null`, and the caller could've passed `null` explicitly anyway. So instead use `== null`:

```dart
class MyClass {
    int x;
    bool b;

    MyClass(int x, [bool b]) {
        if (b == null) {
            // throw exception or assign default value for b
        }
    }
}
```